# How can I collect some hardware profile data during the execution of the Java program with eclipse and JVM monitor?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I've been looking for a way to profile some hardware such as CPU memory usage of Java applications.

I would like to collect the following bits of data at specific points during the execution of the Java program, such as the amount of memory used.

For this purpose, I find eclipse with JVM monitor might help. However JVM monitor might only monitor CPU, threads and memory usage of Java applications, I still not find how to collect profiling data with JVM Monitor yet?

So does anyone know how to collect the data which JVM monitor monitors?

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what do you want to achieve? Maybe I misunderstood something, but as far as I get JVM monitor you use can monitor memory usage which you want (in second paragraph).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my Question!!!  I mean that I want to collect some data such as memory usage during the execution of JAVA program. And I find Eclipse with JVM monitor can monitor memory usage of java applications.But I don't know whether JVM monitor can collect the memory usage of java applications and write the data to file?

Comment: Actually I don't know whether this particular tool can save profiling results to file, sorry :( You may also want to try other profilers - jvisualvm, JProfiler, YourKit.

Comment: fine， Thanks anyway:D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using graphics Performance analyzer from Intel (https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/intel-gpa). GPA gives you real time CPU,Memory FPS and a bunch of other information while you application is running on a real device. You could see at what point in time your application consumes most CPU.